# How to format code blocks in speaker notes written in Markdown with Reveal.js?

Tags: markdown, reveal.js, github-flavored-markdown

I am using Reveal.js 2.6.1 and I'm trying to an external markdown file to render code blocks in speaker notes properly.

My slide deck looks something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' name='viewport' />
    <link href="/stylesheets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/javascripts/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="index">
    <div class='reveal'>
      <div class='slides'>
        <section data-charset='utf-8' data-markdown='basics/basics.html' data-notes='^Notes:' data-vertical='^_' id='basics'></section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/javascripts/head.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/reveal.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
      // Full list of configuration options available here:
      // https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
      Reveal.initialize({
        controls: true,
        progress: true,
        history: true,
        center: true,
        rollingLinks: false,

        theme: Reveal.getQueryHash().theme, // available themes are in /css/theme
        transition: Reveal.getQueryHash().transition || 'default', // default/cube/page/concave/zoom/linear/fade/none

        // Optional libraries used to extend on reveal.js
        dependencies: [
          { src: 'javascripts/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
          { src: 'javascripts/plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
          { src: 'javascripts/plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
          { src: 'javascripts/plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } },
          { src: 'javascripts/plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } },
          { src: 'javascripts/plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.body.classList; } }
        ]
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the external markdown file is:

````
## Title

- Foo
- Bar
```
{foo: bar}
```

Notes:
```
{foo: bar}
```
````

Things are working for the most part (file gets loaded, markdown gets converted), but the code block in the notes gets rendered as an inline code snippet:

```
<p><code>var foo = 'bar';</code></p>
```

Instead of as a code block like it does in the slide:

```
<pre><code>var foo = 'bar';</code></pre>
```

**UPDATE:**

Using code blocks in markdown in notes without using external files, works properly:

````
<section>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <aside class='notes' data-markdown>
    ```
    {a: b};
    return true;
    ```
  </aside>
</section>
````

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I've now filed a [bug](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/777) with the project, as I think maybe that's where the problem resides.

Answer (score 1):

With reveal 3.0.0, a simple fix is to replace in index.html:

`{ src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( 'pre code' ); }, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } },`

with

`{ src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, condition: function() { return true; }, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } },`

This forces the async loading of highlight.js effectively fixing the missing highlight in the code blocks.